# How to send soap(xml) request using libcurl

Tags: c++, xml, curl, gsoap

I am trying to send a SOAP request in xml format to a SOAP service using libcurl but i am getting error like" 500 internal server error" while posting the request in soap service.

I have tried almost all the approaches available online.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * wfp = fopen("res.xml", "w+"); //File pointer to write the soap response
    if (!wfp) {
        perror("Write File Open:");
        //        exit(0);
    }

    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
    header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    header = curl_slist_append(header, "SOAPAction: http://localhost:62634/Service1.svc");
    header = curl_slist_append(header, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
    header = curl_slist_append(header, "Expect:");
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:62634/Service1.svc");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:AddNumbers=\"http://localhost:62634/Service1.svc\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><AddNumbers xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><number1>4</number1><number2>5</number2></AddNumbers></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);  //Gets data to be written to file
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, wfp);  //Writes result to file
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)-1);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that curl is enough  for the SOAP ? I think that you need a SOAP framework like [Apache Axis2 for C](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/) for example.

Comment: Thanks for replying, in PHP  i am able to send  soap request to soap service, so like that i am trying to implement in c++ using libcurl.

Comment: Actually i don't have much more idea about curl related to soap service.

Comment: Two things appear missing. 1) the HTTP content-type header should be "text/xml; charset=utf-8" (SOAP1.1) or "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" (SOAP1.2). And 2) most soap services require a SOAPAction HTTP header, which is specified in the WSDL file that defines the service. Why aren't you using a soap framework such as gsoap that works with cURL? That saves you a lot of time because it generates the code for you and handles the transport details automatically. See https://www.genivia.com/examples/curl/index.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, According to your suggestion , i have changed header content type,but when i have changed content-type header to  application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" after that i am getting error like "  Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8 " .

For gsoap framework, i don't want to depend upon client based application, it should be run individual.

Comment: I am having the same issue, where you able to figure it out or shall I open another question?